# Boost converter switch current computation verification

Tags: power, current, boost

I need to have a boost converter in my design in order to provide 5V to the entire system. According to all datasheets I could gather, the total current of the board should not be above 1.5A. So, the parameters are the following :

| Param | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Vin Min | 2,8 |
| Vin Max | 4,2 |
| Vout | 5 |
| Iout | 1,5 |
| Efficiency | 0,8 |

Using the wordeful app note from TI (https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva372c/slva372c.pdf) and using these equations
[image]

[image]
[image]

I have a max switching current from about 3.75 A. Does it sound correct to you guys ?

Answer (score 0):

3.75A is quite plausible. Make sure to calculate the power dissipation in your MOSFET - even if the FET can handle 5A or so theoretically, it might still overheat due to inadequate cooling.

Comment: Thanks, will do ;)

Answer (score 0):

> *I have a max switching current from about 3.75 A. Does it sound
> correct to you guys?*

Taking account of the output Schottky diode volt drop of about 0.3 volts and, guessing an operating frequency of 100 kHz and inductor value of around 7 μH, with the input voltage at 2.8 volts, the peak current taken from the input source will be around 3.75 amps: -

[image]

[Internet boost converter calculator](http://www.stades.co.uk/Boost%20converter/Boost%20calculator.html)

That particular design will be running in CCM with a duty cycle of about 47%. MOSFET losses might cause the efficiency to drop slightly below 90% but it totally depends on the quality of components you use.